# VBA code to find all hidden folders in directory with WQL and store it in xml file

Tags: vba, wmi, wmi-query, wql

I managed to get all the hidden folders now and the only problem is to store all the information about it into the xml file.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
Dim xdoc
Function CreateFolders(objFile)
  Dim elem
  Dim attr
  set elem = xdoc.createElement("Folders")
  set attr = xdoc.createAttribute("Description")
  attr.value = objFile.Description
  elem.setAttributeNode attr
  set CreateFolders = elem
End Function

Dim FilePath

Dim objFile
Dim root
Dim elem, elem1


Set xdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xdoc.appendChild xdoc.createProcessingInstruction        ("xml", "version=""1.0""     encoding=""utf-8""")
FilePath = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\M.xml"

set root = xdoc.createElement("Folders")
xdoc.appendChild root


strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Directory Hidden = True")
 For Each objFile in colFiles
   Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I found. May be it'll help someone in the future

```
Dim xdoc
Function CreateFolders(objFile)
  Dim elem
  Dim attr
  set elem = xdoc.createElement("Folder")
  set attr = xdoc.createAttribute("Description")
  attr.value = objFile.Description
  elem.setAttributeNode attr
  set CreateFolders = elem
End Function

Dim FilePath
Dim objFile
Dim root
Dim elem, elem1


Set xdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xdoc.appendChild xdoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0""       encoding=""utf-8""")
FilePath = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\My.xml"

set root = xdoc.createElement("Folders")
xdoc.appendChild root

Wscript.Echo "Stage 1 Done"

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Directory Where Hidden = True")
Wscript.Echo "Stage 2 Done"

For Each objFile in colFiles
set elem = CreateFolders(objFile)
root.appendChild elem


Next
Wscript.Echo "Stage 3 Done"
xdoc.Save FilePath
```